# IntelliJ Debug tool window switches from Console to Debugger

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

This will probably sound like a minor issue, but it's completely messing up my workflow:

I have a microservice that I restart frequently to refresh changes. I start in Debug mode, and use the curvy arrow in the upper left of the Debug tool window to stop/start the process.

In the Debug window, there are 2 tabs, Debugger and Console. For weeks, I've kept this on Console, and I can see the service run through startup, and I know when to start hitting endpoints. All of a sudden, whenever I start up, it switches to the Debugger tab, which means I have to manually switch back.

No documentation on this, and didn't find anything with a Google search. Does anyone have something to try?

Thank you

Update:

I start with the focus on Console (the right tab) and it switches to Debugger (the left tab). There is a "Focus on startup" in the context menu for Console, but it has no effect.

[image]

Comment: So, by default, IntelliJ will open up the Debugger tab when you're in Debug mode.  It's likely intentional, as you have symbol information in that window as opposed to the console window.  Is it the case that you'd rather have the console and debug windows side-by-side?

Comment: I'm not actually debugging, and don't have any breakpoints; I just start the process in debug by default in case I want to start debugging without restarting the server. If the two windows can be arranged side-by-side that would solve my problem, but I'd rather it just stick on console, like it always has.

Comment: I've noticed from your screenshot that my configuration of the debug view is different - I have nested output tab within the Debug tool window, not as a separate tab. Maybe that's why it worked for me. I've also come accross this bug which applies to your situation: [IDEA-16948](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-16948). I'll try to look into it tomorrow and update the answer if I find something new

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for. If it's not, could you please add some screenshots to the question which might better illustrate the problem? But if it is, here is what I found:

In the Debug tool window you have tabs like *Output* and *Variables*, which are probably the tabs you are talking about. You can right click any of these tabs and select *Focus On Startup*. You probably have this option selected for the wrong tab. So try selecting it for the *Output* tab.

You can toggle the *Focus On Startup* behavior for other tabs in the Debug tool window too.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I added the screenshot. There is a "Focus on startup" in the context menu for Console, but it has no effect. There is no "Focus on startup" for the Debugger tab, but it aways focuses there on startup. Thanks!

Comment: "Focus on Startup" still has no effect. I'm using 2017.1EAP.